# ReactJS - commands do not run in desired order

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to build a find nearby restaurants app in ReactJS and I am having a problem with displaying array data on the first run of this command below.

What happens is that the first time I fetch data with axios it only load location. The second time I fetch data it also renders the array data on the interface.

I think the problem is with the order of the command I run in this function and on the first run it tries to fetch undefined lat & lng, then after the second time we run it in the same session it renders based on what lat & lng was fetches with the previous run of the function.

Here's the code:

```
currentLocationOnClick = async () => {
    let { lat, lng } = this.state;
    const URL = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=${lat},${lng}&type=restaurant&radius=${5 *
      1000}&key=AIzaSyBpd_v1C8RFh0D39Al97ANZ-eJLO3zrKAQ`;
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      position => {
        this.setState({ lat: position.coords.latitude });
        this.setState({ lng: position.coords.longitude });
      },
      error => {
        console.log('Error getting location');
      }
    );

    let places;
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(URL);
      console.log(response.data);
      places = response.data.results;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    }

    this.setState({ places });
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` is an async function, meaning the function call does **not** block until it finished.

one way of fixing this would be to put your axios call in `position` callback.

For example, something like this:

```
async position => {
const URL = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=${position.coords.latitude},${position.coords.longitude}&type=restaurant&radius=${5 *
      1000}&key=AIzaSyBpd_v1C8RFh0D39Al97ANZ-eJLO3zrKAQ`;

      const response = await axios.get(URL);
      console.log(response.data);
      places = response.data.results;
      this.setState({ places });
      },
```

Another nicer, solution would be to wrap navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition so it's an awaitable function.

something like this:

```
function getCurrentPosition()
{
  return new Promise(resolve => navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => resolve(position)))
}
```

Then you could use it something like this:

```
let position = await getCurrentPosition();
const URL = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=${position.coords.latitude},${position.coords.longitude}&type=restaurant&radius=${5 *
      1000}&key=AIzaSyBpd_v1C8RFh0D39Al97ANZ-eJLO3zrKAQ`;
const response = await axios.get(URL);
```